# No qualifying bean of type 'com.atlassian.confluence.user.UserAccessor' available error

Tags: java, confluence, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am developing a Confluence Server plugin and I keep getting this error whenever I access my servlet module.

> com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$InitializationException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name ‘dso.intern.plugin.BulkUserCreatorToolServlet’: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type ‘com.atlassian.confluence.user.UserAccessor’ available: expected
> at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

Here's my code:

```
@Named("BulkUserCreatorToolServlet")
public class BulkUserCreatorToolServlet extends HttpServlet{

    private final UserAccessor userAccessor;

    public BulkUserCreatorToolServlet(UserAccessor userAccessor){
        this.userAccessor = userAccessor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        // Create a factory for disk-based file items
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

        // Configure a repository (to ensure a secure temp location is used)
        ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext();
        File repository = (File) servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
        factory.setRepository(repository);

        // Create a new file upload handler
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        try{
            //Parse the request to get file items
            List<FileItem> fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

            // Process the uploaded items
            Iterator<FileItem> iter = fileItems.iterator();
            String contentType = null;
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                FileItem item = iter.next();

                if(!item.isFormField()){
                    String content = item.getString();
                    StringReader sReader = new StringReader(content);
                    Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(sReader);
                    for(CSVRecord record : records){
                        String username = record.get("ï»¿Username");    //UTF-8 BOM
                        String fullname = record.get("Fullname");
                        String email = record.get("Email");
                        String password = record.get("Password");
                        String groupsToBeAddedInto = record.get("GroupsToBeAddedInto");

                        DefaultUser defaultUser = new DefaultUser(username, fullname, email);
                        ConfluenceUser newUser = userAccessor.createUser(defaultUser, Credential.unencrypted(password));
                     userAccessor.addMembership(UserAccessor.GROUP_CONFLUENCE_USERS, username);
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            
            response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");

            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html><head>");
            out.println("<meta name=\"decorator\" content=\"atl.admin\" />");
            out.println("<title>Response Page</title></head></html>");

        }
        catch(FileUploadException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

UserAccessor is not managed by spring container.

```
@Named("BulkUserCreatorToolServlet")
public class BulkUserCreatorToolServlet extends HttpServlet{

    private final UserAccessor userAccessor;

    public BulkUserCreatorToolServlet(UserAccessor userAccessor){
        this.userAccessor = userAccessor;
    }
```

```
@Named("BulkUserCreatorToolServlet")
@Compoment //add this may let it managed by spring container
public class BulkUserCreatorToolServlet extends HttpServlet{

    @Autowried // add this may let it managed by spring container
    private final UserAccessor userAccessor;

    public BulkUserCreatorToolServlet(UserAccessor userAccessor){
        this.userAccessor = userAccessor;
    }

Please have a try.
```

Comment: Hi @AhahaGe, thanks for replying. I found a solution before I read your comment but nonetheless, thank you! 

Solution: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Why-is-there-an-org-springframework-beans-factory/qaq-p/506686